# Reloading iframe instead opens new tab - Firefox 21.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, iframe

I made a small webpage for some of my friends, and one of them is having an issue.

I'm using javascript to reload an iframe like so:

```
<a href="javascript:var pl=$('#player iframe')[0];pl.src=pl.src;">↺ Repair</a>
```

Using jQuery, but for one of my friends using Firefox 21.0 on Windows 7, this causes the page to instead entirely change to the iframe itself; specifically, the livestream widget.

Livestream tends to bork fairly frequently, so the repair button is fairly important to the watching experience. Is there a way I could implement this differently so this doesn't happen to him?

Comment: `pl.contentWindow.location.reload(true);` ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough to know how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: try replacing `pl.src=pl.src;` for what I've posted

Comment: Didn't work for him, and that disabled the function entirely for me.

Comment: aw, well it's was woth the shot, maybe try creating a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XeXkS/

Comment: It calls the reload function whenever you resize the video, and the video resize works for him, so it appears that placement of the script within the HTML is what's causing the problem, not the script itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding to the click event instead:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="repair"">↺ Repair</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#repair').click(function(e){
    var pl=$('#player iframe')[0];pl.src=pl.src;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, but it appears nothing happens now. Did I do something wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/rfNpa/

Comment: Well, it works in the fiddle, but not on the page. Must have something to do with the loading, maybe.

Comment: Try wrapping it inside a jQuery function like the rest of your code

Comment: It needed to be inside on Document Ready. Otherwise, that worked!